# Can a square be partitioned into mutually non-congruent triangles all of same area and perimeter?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, tiling

It is known that the plane cannot be tiled by pair-wise non-congruent triangles all having same area and same perimeter (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04504).

**Question:** Can a square be partitioned into some finite number of pair-wise non-congruent triangles all with same area and perimeter? If "no", does any regular polygon allow such a triangulation?

**Note:** If one needs the non-congruent triangular pieces only to have same area, a square can be cut into at least some finite number n of such triangles (as just an example, a 20X20 square centered on the origin can be cut into 40 mutually non-congruent triangles all of area 10 and all sharing a vertex at the point (3,1) and the cut lines radiating from there). I don't know for what values n a square can be so partitioned - for odd n, the answer is certainly "impossible" by Monsky's theorem but beyond that, what?

An earlier and wider question: [To partition planar convex regions into n mutually non-congruent convex pieces of equal area and perimeter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415859/to-partition-planar-convex-regions-into-n-mutually-non-congruent-convex-pieces-o)

Comment: definitely not an odd number of triangles with the same area (to say nothing of perimeter). cf. Monsky's Theorem, which I describe a learning path for briefly [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394034/22971).

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but doesn't this follow from theorem 6 in the paper?

Comment: belated thanks! i was the one who missed that theorem and its implication. indeed, "Let k ≥ 4. In any tiling of a convex k-gon with finitely many triangles, there are two triangles that share an edge" - so the answer is clearly NO.

Comment: to mark the question as answered, your observation may be given as an answer.