# Polyhedra inscribed in a sphere with mutually non-congruent, equal area faces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes

Two constrained versions of the main question given in this post: [Polyhedrons with mutually non-congruent faces, all of equal area](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466689/polyhedrons-with-mutually-non-congruent-faces-all-of-equal-area). An earlier post that could be related: [Cutting a spherical surface into mutually non-congruent pieces of equal area](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415631/cutting-a-spherical-surface-into-mutually-non-congruent-pieces-of-equal-area)

- for any integer $n>4$, are there $n$-hedra inscribed in a sphere (all vertices lying on the spherical surface) such that the faces are all of equal area and mutually non-congruent?
- If one asks the above question about $n$-hedra with equal area and mutually non-congruent faces such that *a sphere touches all its faces internally*, is that a qualitative change?

Note: The questions can be asked with "area" replaced by "perimeter", "diameter" and so forth. And I don't know if replacing the "sphere" with some other closed convex surface would have implications.